# How to deploy frontend angular app and backend Django app on GCP at same time?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, docker-container

I have a Angular project and Django (backend) project. As of now I am using Gitlab CI/CD to deploy individual app on Google Cloud Platform. But In production environment in future I want to deploy my code at the same time. How to do this on Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools for [CI/CD on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd/). You could use [Google App Engine with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories). You can find a pretty straightforward tutorial [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automatically-deploy-to-google-app-engine-with-gitlab-ci-d1c7237cbe11). Or you could take advantage of the [Gitlab Google Kubernetes Engine integration](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/google-cloud-platform/). You can find an example on the official documentation by going [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-production-ready-gitlab-on-gke).

Comment: But how to do this for two different repository? I have my individual repositories for backend and frontend.

Comment: Are you using [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/) for both backend and frontend applications? Are your applications hosted on different  [Google Cloud Platform projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)? Please dig a little bit further on your current architecture.

Comment: I am maintaining backend and frontend repositories on gitlab. My frontend app is hosted on Google app engine and backend on compute engine. I've setup ci/cd pipeline to deploy my frontend code on Google cloud app engine and same for backend app.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html. But I wouldn't rely too much on deployment "at the same time" - the 2 deployments (on 2 different GCP products) cannot be made atomic, there will always be room for that assumption to not be exactly true.

Comment: what service do you use? App Engine? Another one? Solution depends of this!

Comment: Given the current nature of the specific architecture being used: 1. AngularJS frontend deployed to App Engine and 2. Django backend deployed to Compute Engine.

Comment: In order to achieve your current purpose my first choice would be to migrate your Django backend to App Engine [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) or [Flex](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) and use any of [the available methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/communicating-between-services) to communicate your frontend and backend services.

Comment: or you could try to [containerize](https://cloud.google.com/containers/) your whole application and deploy it on [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app).